# Why is a ClassInitialize decorated method making all my tests fail?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I understand, from MSDN, that `ClassInitialize` is to mark a method that will do setup code for all tests, once, before all tests run. When I include such a method in the abridged fixture below, all tests fail. As soon as I comment it out, they pass again.

```
[TestClass]
public class AuthenticationTests
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public void SetupAuth()
    {
        var x = 0;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRegisterMemberInit()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the test failure say?

Comment: Ooops. The error text part of the tests window was 'minimised' away to the bottom. I genuinely didn't know it was even there. Thanks Jon, you made me look all over and eventually find it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `[ClassInitialize]` decorated method should be static and take exactly one parameter of type `TestContext`:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetupAuth(TestContext context)
{
    var x = 0;
}
```

In fact, if I copy-paste your code into a clean VS project, the testrunner explains exactly that in the error message:

> Method UnitTestProject1.AuthenticationTests.SetupAuth has wrong signature. The method must be static, public, does not return a value and should take a single parameter of type TestContext.

Comment: thanks. As I explained in a comment on my question, that error in the test runner was hidden, i.e. the panel it displays in was too small for me to see.

Answer (score 2):

Method marked with `[ClassInitialize]`:

1. Apply to only one method of a test class.
2. The class must be sealed, i.e. not inherited.
3. The method has to be public static.
4. The method must pass a `TestContext` parameter.
5. The Method does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015, the failure to have the TestContext parameter causes this most unhelpful error to be output when you run the test (in case anyone is searching on the exception, like I was):

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TypeInspectionException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll