# Fails to execute classes with ClassInitialize method present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I face an awkward situation - all test classes that have [ClassInitialize] method present fail to execute all test methods inside.

Example:

```
[TestClass]
public class ChargeAccountServiceTests
{
    private static PrivateType ChargeAccountService_Accessor;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void InitializeClass(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext context)
    {
         ChargeAccountService_Accessor = new PrivateType(typeof(ChargeAccountService));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFixOMRHappySHA()
    {
          //TEST LOGIC
    }
}
```

Causes test agent to throw following exception:

```
Test Name:  TestFixOMRHappySHA
Test FullName:  ChargeAccountServiceTests.TestFixOMRHappySHA
Test Source:    \ChargeAccountServiceTests.cs : line 22
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00
```

Result Message:

> Method ChargeAccountServiceTests.InitializeClass has wrong signature.  Parameter 1 should be of type Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext.

This test has been working few days ago. Test project target is .NET 3.5

Comment: Did you upgrade your project recently?

Comment: I'd guess that you are referencing an incorrect version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.  Try removing and re-adding that reference.

Comment: This is a DLL Hell problem.  The TextContext class that you use isn't the same one that the test runner expects.  Type identity isn't just the namespace and type name, it also includes the assembly it came from.  You've got a reference to the wrong UnitTestFramework assembly version.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got resolved it, by applying combination of tips I found:

1. One of MSTest project was targeted to 4.0 while others to 3.5 - so I had to change it and rebuild fakes.
2. I removed Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll reference and added it again to all my test projects
3. I found an old version of vsdmi file in my solution - removed
4. I removed and created Local.testsettings
5. Restarted VS

Answer (score 2):

From my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749537/what-does-method-classinitialize-has-wrong-signature-mean), I had the same issue, for me it worked to

1. Remove the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
2. Right click the project and select "Add > Unit test..." which restores the reference with the correct version.

Comment: This doesn't work *for me*, I put my answer in the linked question which is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but for [AssemblyInitialize] not [ClassInitialize].

Removing the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework and re-adding v10.0.0.0 fixed the problem for me.

It turned out my different test projects were referencing different versions, and making them all consistently point to 10.0.0.0 fixed the problem.