# .NET Problem removing TestContext from Unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a c# unit test project (.NET 4.8).
My unit test are using a .testsetting file that I want to remove.
In my unit test I use TestContext too:

```
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return testContextInstance; }
            set { testContextInstance = value; }
        }

        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
            LoadSettings(testContext.DeploymentDirectory);
        }
```

First I removed the .testsettings file, then I modified the unit test removing the TestContext:

```
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void MyClassInitialize()
        {
            LoadSettings(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        }
```

My problem is when I run the unit test I got this error:

> MyClassInitialize has wrong signature. The method must be static,
>   public, does not return a value and should take a single parameter of
>   type TestContext.

Looking at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749537/what-does-method-classinitialize-has-wrong-signature-mean), I changed the version of "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnittestFramework" from 10.0.0.0 to 10.1.0.0 with no success.

Before run the tests I unchecked the .testsettings from "Test" menu and then I deleted it.

Currently use Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.2.

I still got the same error. Do I need to reference another dll or another version? Do I need to install something?

**UPDATE:**

Here how I added the reference:
[image]

Here the row added by Visual Studio in the .csproj file:

> Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework,Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,processorArchitecture=MSIL"

And It is how look the reference properties in Visual Studio:
[image]

I still got the error, but the strange thing is If I restart Visual Studio in the reference property I continue to see the old version (10.0.0.0)!!!

[image]

I tried also with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.16. Same result!

Comment: In the first code block you have parentheses after `ClassInitialize`, removing those doesn't help?

Comment: Nope, as you can see in the second code block I already removed that with no luck.

Comment: Yeah, but there you have no `TestContext` argument :)

Comment: @aage I want to remove .testsettings and all usage of TestContext

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I forgot to mention that. I am going to update my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, a method decorated with the `ClassInitializeAttribute` must take a `TestContext` parameter.

You can just ignore it if you don't ever indend to use a `.testsettings` file, but you cannot remove the parameter.

Comment: It works, thank you. I was thinking about a wrong dll loading...